# Not getting desired output on left join in spark scala

Tags: sql, apache-spark

I have 2 datasets[ReconEntity] where ReconEntity is :

```
case class ReconEntity(rowId: String,
                       groupId: String,
                       amounts: List[Amount],
                       processingDate: Long,
                       attributes: Map[String, String],
                       entityType: String,
                       isDuplicate: String)
```

First Dataset looks like :

```
     +-----+-------+------------------+--------------+----------+-----------+
     |rowId|groupId|            amount|processingDate|attributes|isDuplicate|
     +-----+-------+------------------+--------------+----------+-----------+
     |   C1|     G1|USD,10.00000000...|    1551021334|  rowId,C1|      false|
     |   C1|     G1|USD,10.00000000...|    1551011017|  rowId,C1|       true|
     |   C1|     G1|USD,10.00000000...|    1551011017|  rowId,C1|       true|
     |   C1|     G1|USD,10.00000000...|    1551011017|  rowId,C1|       true|
     |   C2|     G2|USD,2.000000000...|    1551011017|  rowId,C2|      false|
     |   C3|     G2|USD,6.000000000...|    1551011459|  rowId,C3|      false|
     |   C3|     G2|USD,6.000000000...|    1551011017|  rowId,C3|       true|
     +-----+-------+------------------+--------------+----------+-----------+
```

and the second dataset looks like :

```
     +-----+-------+------------------+--------------+----------+-----------+
     |rowId|groupId|            amount|processingDate|attributes|isDuplicate|
     +-----+-------+------------------+--------------+----------+-----------+
     |   C2|     G2|USD,2.000000000...|    1551011017|  rowId,C2|      false|
     |   C3|     G2|USD,6.000000000...|    1551011459|  rowId,C3|      false|
     +-----+-------+------------------+--------------+----------+-----------+
```

And I want the resultant to look like this :

```
     +-----+-------+------------------+--------------+----------+-----------+
     |rowId|groupId|            amount|processingDate|attributes|isDuplicate|
     +-----+-------+------------------+--------------+----------+-----------+
     |   C1|     G1|USD,10.00000000...|    1551021334|  rowId,C1|       true|
     |   C1|     G1|USD,10.00000000...|    1551011017|  rowId,C1|       true|
     |   C1|     G1|USD,10.00000000...|    1551011017|  rowId,C1|       true|
     |   C1|     G1|USD,10.00000000...|    1551011017|  rowId,C1|       true|
     |   C2|     G2|USD,2.000000000...|    1551011017|  rowId,C2|      false|
     |   C3|     G2|USD,6.000000000...|    1551011459|  rowId,C3|      false|
     |   C3|     G2|USD,6.000000000...|    1551011017|  rowId,C3|       true|
     +-----+-------+------------------+--------------+----------+-----------+
```

I am joining the 2 datasets using left join and if the rowId is not present in second dataset, I am marking the value of isDuplicate flag as true, otherwise the original value in the resultant dataset. The logic is:

```
inputEntries.as("inputDataset").join(otherEntries.as("otherDataset"),
      col("inputDataset.rowId") === col("otherDataset.rowId"), "left")
      .select(
        col("inputDataset.rowId"),
        col("inputDataset.groupId"),
        col("inputDataset.amounts"),
        col("inputDataset.processingDate"),
        col("inputDataset.attributes"),
        col("inputDataset.entityType"),
        when(
          col("otherDataset.rowId").isNull, TRUE
        ).otherwise(col("inputDataset.isDuplicate")).as(IS_DUPLICATE)
      ).as[ReconEntity]
```

Here the joinKey is rowId.This logic is working fine in local, but when I am trying to run the spark job, the results are not as expected. I am not very well versed with joins, wanted to know whether my logic for the desired output is correct or not. And what would be the output of left join of the 2 datasets.

Comment: can you add a sample for the output which is not as expected? (From the details you provided, it should work; Only for: `if the rowId is not present in second dataset, I am marking the value of isDuplicate flag as false` --> In code you are marking as `TRUE`)

Comment: I have pasted the desired output in the question itself. My bad, I am making it true, form the result you can see that c1 was not present in the second dataset so the corresponding value of isDuplicate becomes true for c1. Also can anyone explain if the left join is the right kind of join here, or do I need some other join.

Comment: The expected result vs your description is still very confusing, can you please be more specific?  eg: Your statement `I am joining the 2 datasets using left join and if the rowId is not present in second dataset, I am marking the value of isDuplicate flag as false` contradicts with the first result in expected result: `C1 is not present in second dataset, but still isDuplicate for first row is true`

Comment: Have corrected the question description, I am making isDuplicate as true where it is false for the rowids which are not present in second dataset like c1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the given requirement, the left join will be the correct choice.

Can you share the difference you see in the spark-job ouput? The only issue with the current solution will be when you have duplicates in the second dataset (otherEntries). In this case, each row in first dataset will get matched with the duplicate row, creating multiple entries.

Since we only need to check for `rowId` column, you can use a `deduplicate` operation to keep only unique rows in the second dataset to avoid duplicates after the join.

Below is a working code, with the de-deduplicate included and sample output for the join before and after de-deduplication.

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset
import spark.implicits._

// Class definitions
case class Amount(currency: String, value: Double)
case class ReconEntity(
  rowId: String,
  groupId: String,
  amounts: List[Amount],
  processingDate: Long,
  attributes: Map[String, String],
  entityType: String,
  isDuplicate: String
)

// First Dataset
val inputEntries: Dataset[ReconEntity] = Seq(
    ReconEntity("C1", "G1", List(Amount("USD", 10.0), Amount("EUR", 50.0)), 1551021334, Map("rowId" -> "C1"), "E1", "false"),
    ReconEntity("C1", "G1", List(Amount("USD", 10.0), Amount("EUR", 50.0)), 1551011017, Map("rowId" -> "C1"), "E1", "true"),
    ReconEntity("C1", "G1", List(Amount("USD", 10.0), Amount("EUR", 50.0)), 1551011017, Map("rowId" -> "C1"), "E1", "true"),
    ReconEntity("C1", "G1", List(Amount("USD", 10.0), Amount("EUR", 50.0)), 1551011017, Map("rowId" -> "C1"), "E1", "true"),
    ReconEntity("C2", "G2", List(Amount("USD", 2.0), Amount("EUR", 50.0)), 1551011017, Map("rowId" -> "C2"), "E1", "false"),
    ReconEntity("C3", "G2", List(Amount("USD", 6.0), Amount("EUR", 50.0)), 1551011459, Map("rowId" -> "C3"), "E1", "false"),
    ReconEntity("C3", "G2", List(Amount("USD", 6.0), Amount("EUR", 50.0)), 1551011017, Map("rowId" -> "C3"), "E1", "true")
).toDS()
// Second Dataset (includes a duplicate for "C3")
val otherEntries: Dataset[ReconEntity] = Seq(
    ReconEntity("C2", "G2", List(Amount("USD", 2.0), Amount("EUR", 50.0)), 1551011017, Map("rowId" -> "C2"), "E1", "false"),
    ReconEntity("C3", "G2", List(Amount("USD", 6.0), Amount("EUR", 50.0)), 1551011459, Map("rowId" -> "C3"), "E1", "false"),
    ReconEntity("C3", "G2", List(Amount("USD", 6.0), Amount("EUR", 50.0)), 1551011460, Map("rowId" -> "C3"), "E1", "false")
).toDS()

// Sample Output with left join
inputEntries.join(otherEntries, Seq("rowId"), "left").show()

// Due to duplicates in second dataset, there are 4 rows for "C3" instead of 2 expected
// +-----+-------+--------------------+--------------+-------------+----------+-----------+-------+--------------------+--------------+-------------+----------+-----------+
// |rowId|groupId|             amounts|processingDate|   attributes|entityType|isDuplicate|groupId|             amounts|processingDate|   attributes|entityType|isDuplicate|
// +-----+-------+--------------------+--------------+-------------+----------+-----------+-------+--------------------+--------------+-------------+----------+-----------+
// |   C1|     G1|[{USD, 10.0}, {EU...|    1551021334|{rowId -> C1}|        E1|      false|   null|                null|          null|         null|      null|       null|
// |   C1|     G1|[{USD, 10.0}, {EU...|    1551011017|{rowId -> C1}|        E1|       true|   null|                null|          null|         null|      null|       null|
// |   C1|     G1|[{USD, 10.0}, {EU...|    1551011017|{rowId -> C1}|        E1|       true|   null|                null|          null|         null|      null|       null|
// |   C1|     G1|[{USD, 10.0}, {EU...|    1551011017|{rowId -> C1}|        E1|       true|   null|                null|          null|         null|      null|       null|
// |   C2|     G2|[{USD, 2.0}, {EUR...|    1551011017|{rowId -> C2}|        E1|      false|     G2|[{USD, 2.0}, {EUR...|    1551011017|{rowId -> C2}|        E1|      false|
// |   C3|     G2|[{USD, 6.0}, {EUR...|    1551011459|{rowId -> C3}|        E1|      false|     G2|[{USD, 6.0}, {EUR...|    1551011460|{rowId -> C3}|        E1|      false|
// |   C3|     G2|[{USD, 6.0}, {EUR...|    1551011459|{rowId -> C3}|        E1|      false|     G2|[{USD, 6.0}, {EUR...|    1551011459|{rowId -> C3}|        E1|      false|
// |   C3|     G2|[{USD, 6.0}, {EUR...|    1551011017|{rowId -> C3}|        E1|       true|     G2|[{USD, 6.0}, {EUR...|    1551011460|{rowId -> C3}|        E1|      false|
// |   C3|     G2|[{USD, 6.0}, {EUR...|    1551011017|{rowId -> C3}|        E1|       true|     G2|[{USD, 6.0}, {EUR...|    1551011459|{rowId -> C3}|        E1|      false|
// +-----+-------+--------------------+--------------+-------------+----------+-----------+-------+--------------------+--------------+-------------+----------+-----------+


// Create a result with de-duplication of second dataset on join key (rowId)
val result = inputEntries.as("inputDataset").join(
    otherEntries.dropDuplicates("rowId").as("otherDataset"),
    Seq("rowId"), 
    "left"
    ).select(
        col("inputDataset.rowId"),
        col("inputDataset.groupId"),
        col("inputDataset.amounts"),
        col("inputDataset.processingDate"),
        col("inputDataset.attributes"),
        col("inputDataset.entityType"),
        when(
          col("otherDataset.rowId").isNull, lit("true")
        ).otherwise(col("inputDataset.isDuplicate")).as("isDuplicate")
      ).as[ReconEntity]

// Output
result.show()
// +-----+-------+--------------------+--------------+-------------+----------+-----------+
// |rowId|groupId|             amounts|processingDate|   attributes|entityType|isDuplicate|
// +-----+-------+--------------------+--------------+-------------+----------+-----------+
// |   C1|     G1|[{USD, 10.0}, {EU...|    1551021334|{rowId -> C1}|        E1|       true|
// |   C1|     G1|[{USD, 10.0}, {EU...|    1551011017|{rowId -> C1}|        E1|       true|
// |   C1|     G1|[{USD, 10.0}, {EU...|    1551011017|{rowId -> C1}|        E1|       true|
// |   C1|     G1|[{USD, 10.0}, {EU...|    1551011017|{rowId -> C1}|        E1|       true|
// |   C2|     G2|[{USD, 2.0}, {EUR...|    1551011017|{rowId -> C2}|        E1|      false|
// |   C3|     G2|[{USD, 6.0}, {EUR...|    1551011459|{rowId -> C3}|        E1|      false|
// |   C3|     G2|[{USD, 6.0}, {EUR...|    1551011017|{rowId -> C3}|        E1|       true|
// +-----+-------+--------------------+--------------+-------------+----------+-----------+
```